# How to use the regex split filter in the datafusion?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion

I'm using Google Cloud Platform DataFusion products.

Does it supposed to put a regular expression in the Regex Path Filter part in the Advanced section of the GCS Properties? e.g) /[0-9]

But, If i enter a value in the Regex Path Filter and run the data pipeline, "Output records have not been generated for stage GCS. Please verify your logic, or try sending more data."

I would appreciate it if you could give me an example of how to write in the Regex Path Filter secion.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is an Open issue in **CDAP** for updating its documentation about ***Regex Path Filter*** field, [here](https://cdap.atlassian.net/browse/CDAP-17249).

The ***Regex Path Filter*** is used only to filter files, using Regex according to this [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

For example, you can write  `gs://data_directory/*/file_prefix*` to filter the documents by file prefix or `gs://data_directory/.*\.csv` to filter the files by extension. Whereas ***Path*** points to GCS directory, such as `gs://data_directory`.

Comment: Can't I filter the data_directory?

Comment: To apply txt only to filter
Added filter value as gs://data_directory/.*\.txt.
But I keep getting the error statement as below.
"Output records have not been generated for stage "GCS". Please verify your logic, or try sending more data."

Comment: Can you describe more about your process? Did you add the filter in the GCS Source  Properties?

Comment: Thank you for your response. First I entered `/.*\.txt` in the **regex path filter** entry box of GCS properties. The intention is to filter txt files only. But I don't think it's working well. **Path** is listed as `gs:data_directory/` . @Alexandre Moraes

Comment: I understand,  so you are using the GCS connector as a source. Can you set **Path**  to gs://data_directory ? Also, can you share the error you with your failed pipeline?

Comment: Errors don't come out. However, if I create a data pipeline, i cannot check the values of Out and In. I had a hunch that this would not carry out the data pipeline.

Comment: If I understood correctly your pipeline is executed successfully. Right? Can you elaborate more about what is your process? Also, if the output of the pipeline is correct?